# Words from the list inside folders with output of match words and name of the folder in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

Could someone help me to create a query in Unix with:

For eg. I have a Folder with another folders inside and so one...

[image]

Also I have a list with words I need to find inside these folders: **words_i_need_to_find.txt**. As output I want to have **.csv** file with information:

1. Words from the list
2. Name of the folder where this word was found (for eg. if word from the list was in another folders inside Folder 1 I just want to have the name of this "main" folder) without duplicates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where are these words stored? Do you mean they are stored in files inside these folders or you mean the folder names will have these words?

Comment: They are stored in a files inside these folders.